# ActiveStorageを使った画像の管理を複数のモデル、コントローラーで可能？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

現在作成している画像投稿Webアプリで画像が投稿できるようActiveStorageを導入していますが、また同じWebアプリ内の画像投稿ページとは別ページ（別コントローラー/モデル）の部分でも画像投稿ができるようにしく写真投稿機能ページとは別のモデル（food_model）に写真投稿機能と同じように以下のように記述をしましたが、画像は保存されませんでした。

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one_attached :food_image
end
```

一つのモデル/テーブルに複数の画像を保存する方法はたくさん見つけたのですが、複数のモデルに同じActiveStorageを使って画像を投稿する方法を見つける事ができず、そもそもこれはできない仕様なのか？と思い質問をさせて頂きました。
私がしようとしている事を行うには、ActiveStorageのテーブルを新たに作成する必要があるのか？（そもそもそれができるのか...）もしくは、全く別の方法で画像投稿機能を実装する必要があるのかなど....
もしご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて頂けますと大変助かります。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すいません、自己解決しました。
viewファイルのtext_fieldにきちんとfood_imageと記述していなかったのが問題でした。。。
きちんと切り分けをせず質問をあげてしまい失礼致しました。